# sorting Name And Address array on cell label w.r.t. each other

Tags: iphone

i have searched a lot but not able two sort my array a/c to requirement

i used this code:

```
[array1 sortArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:) withPairedMutableArrays:arrForName, arrForAddress, nil];
```

thanks

Comment: I think we're going to need a bit more context to answer this question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two arrays into a dictionary as keys and values

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrForAddress forKeys:arrForName];
// Sort the first array
NSArray *sortedFirstArray = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
// Sort the second array based on the sorted first array
arrForAddress=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
NSArray *sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]]; 
// arrForAddress = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]]; 
[arrForAddress addObjectsFromArray:sortedSecondArray];
NSLog(@"arrangesort......%@",arrForAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the NSArray Class Reference there isn't a `- sortArrayUsingSelector:withPairedMutableArrays:` method. Neither on the NSMutableArray Class Reference. If you want, you can use other methods like the `NSMutableArray` `sortUsingSelector:` method.